# Standards for Test Scenario

Tags: manual-testing, qa-developer, test-planning, qa-process

Is there any standards to create Scenarios, so that every QA will cover all the defects?

Comment: Short/Most apt answer "No".

Answer (score 3):

> so that every QA will cover all the defects

Short answer: No, because testing is an open-ended investigation process.

Long answer: [Exploratory Testing 3.0](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/1509)